# Azure devops fails on warnings with 'fail on standard error' set to true

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have an inline PowerShell task on an Azure DevOps ci pipeline that requires any warnings to be ignored, however, any errors fail the task and stop the build.

I had originally set the 'fail on standard error' to true, but because all errors and warnings are written to stderr this will fail on any warning.

The below I tried with 'fail on standard error' to false.  Which although noticed the error did not fail the task.

```
sfdx partial:lsapp:build
if ($exitCode -ne 0)
{    
Write-Output (\"[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0.\" -f $exitCode)
}
[Environment]::Exit($exitCode)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the salesforce cli writes warnings to stderr. In that case there is not much you can do to separate warnings and errors in the inline PowerShell task in which you execute the salesforce command.

But if you want to fail the pipeline based on an exit code, you can still use a workaround: Save the exit code in a pipeline variable and evaluate it in a separate task that has `failOnStderr: true` and fails if needed:

```yaml
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      #sfdx partial:lsapp:build
      $exitCode = 1    # Setting this for testing
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sfdxExitCode;]$exitCode"

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $exitCode = $(sfdxExitCode)
      if ($exitCode -ne 0)
      {    
          Write-Error ("Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
      }
    failOnStderr: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your scenario, you could change the Azure DevOps pipeline so that it doesn't stop when an error occurs - this is the "continue on error" flag, which can be set as follows in a YAML Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
- task: "Test@1"
  continueOnError: true
```

and for classic pipelines, you can check the "Continue on error" checkbox.

For more information, you can read through this Azure DevOps documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: That doesn't work as npm warnings are printed to standard error therefore will fail build